# WCF Data Service with EF fails to expose imported functions

Tags: entity-framework, function, stored-procedures, import, wcf-data-services

(I am also using .NET 4.0 and VS 2010.)

I created a function import returning a complex type, as explained at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx. The function import and new complex type appear in my .edmx file and in the Designer.cs file. However, the function does not appear when I view the service in the browser, and when I add or update a service reference in the client project, the function does not appear there either - as is to be expected, given the first result.

Creating an imported function and using it seems conceptually very simple and straightforward, and one would think it would just work, as Microsoft's step-by-step instructions appear to suggest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716672.aspx#Y798 (which article shows the SP returning entity types - I tried this also, and it doesn't work for me either).

This blog post shows the addition of a method to the DataService class, which Microsoft's instructions omit: http://www.codegain.com/articles/wcf/miscellaneous/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-wcf-data-service.aspx I tried adding one method returning a list of entity types and another returning a list of complex types, and still had no success. I still could not access the functions, either directly via the browser or from the client application via a service reference.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Did you allow access to the operations (SetServiceOperationAccessRule)?

Answer (score 1):

config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);

MS would do well to add a note to the walkthroughs stating that the above bit of code must be there. (It may be better to enable each operation explicitly than to use "*".)

http://www.codegain.com/articles/wcf/miscellaneous/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-wcf-data-service.aspx shows that line of code. Also, something it is there in the code, commented out, when one creates the WCF Data Service. Some of us like to delete commented-out code that we aren't using and that seems irrelevant - perhaps doing so a bit prematurely, sometimes.